# Modify celery loggers level

Tags: python, celery

It's first time I'm trying to dive into celery this deep.

I'm running celery worker generated many INFO logs in this form:

```
INFO:celery.worker.job:Task XXXX succeeded in XXX: None

INFO:celery.worker.strategy:Received task:
```

I want to change it to DEBUG instead.

I've found some related information [HERE](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/_modules/celery/app/log.html), [HERE](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3599) and [HERE](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/11/06/celery-task-logger-format/)

and tried playing with the logger inside but didn't find a way to modify this log level from my celery.py file. also tried some environment vars that I thought to be related but it didn't help as well.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as easy as passing `-l DEBUG` to your Celery worker.

For more details run something like `celery -A <celeryapp> worker --help` (change `<celeryapp>` to be the same as what you used to run your Celery worker) and you will get something like:

```
  -l, --loglevel [DEBUG|INFO|WARNING|ERROR|CRITICAL|FATAL]
                                  Logging level.
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. I've tried.